# Garage door opener surge protector

Tags: garage-door-opener

I recently replaced my garage door opener after it was fried in a lightning storm.  To prevent this from happening again I was thinking about buying an 15 amp Isobar surge protector.

The opener is a 1/2 hp Chamberlain whisper drive.  Would an Isobar work on this garage door opener?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the manufacture of the surge protector and the garage door opener.  They usually have the knowledge of what works and doesn't.  Here, you will be waiting for a user that just might have the experience.  Also, have you looked at getting a house surge protector that is installed at your breaker panel?

Answer (score 1):

Does your garage door opener plug into an outlet located nearby?  If so the answer is yes, you can just use a plug mounted protector. It does not need to be specific to your opener model or type:

[image]

But if you've had a problem like this, your better bet may be a Whole House unit.  And your best bet is to use both.

I created a little guide Whole House surge protection over here:
http://obviously.com/1482/Whole-House-Surge-Protectors
(I was working on protecting a fire alarm and some boiler motors, but the principle is the same).

Be warned that "*power strip surge protectors, despite impressive sounding warranties, have a limited record in protecting devices.  Some are poorly designed, others are actually fraudulent knock offs*".  The whole house ones are only made by respected companies and they do actually work.

Comment: The guide you're linking to appears broken.  The "guide" page has a few paragraphs of text that doesn't go beyond what one is, and the "tasklist" page shows multiple errors and has no content at all.